# ListView different readings

Tags: c#, winforms, debugging, listview

I have a code that called from another class than mainform.

```
    public void add_to_reg(ListViewItem tmp)
    {
         if (this.InvokeRequired)
                this.Invoke(new Action(() => add_to_reg_impl(tmp)));
         else
            add_to_reg_impl(tmp);
    }

    private void add_to_reg_impl(ListViewItem item)
    {
        lst_reg.Items.Add(item);
        lst_reg.Refresh();
        this.Refresh();
    }
```

the problem is that the items are not added.
but if i add Debug.WriteLine(lst_reg); to this code above, it shows me that the number of items raising.

but if i put Debug.WriteLine(lst_reg); in button called event it shows me that the listview is empty.

any ideas?

Comment: Can you show us the code of the button?

Comment: from another class.     the button code is the one generated automatically by visual studio when you add a button to the graphics.